# How to make sure that content is only rendered within an iframe

Tags: iframe, curl, detection

I am wondering how to make sure that I only ever show/render the content (send the code to the client) if the content is loaded in an iframe in a real browser, similar to the way Facebook checks when to display their like buttons and other social utilities.

There, when trying to simply load the content using curl, even when sending cookies, session details and user agent details, it still returns nothing. When trying to load the content outside an iframe, one receives nothing. How can that be achieved? I guess it is all but a simple process that involves multiple steps. I am especially interested in the first one, namely how to detect that it is really sent from a browser and not simply curled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for your server to detect if it was sent using browser or curl, as the headers are easily forged.

Comment: what about using difficult-to-compute javascript to add a custom cookie upon loading that page and also loading another one, which then checks if that cookie was added?

Comment: you can try to do that, but it won't prevent from the data theft, it will only slow people down, if the data is valuable enough for someone to try, they will